# Validation issue in name field causes the page to hang

Tags: denial-of-service, data-validation

I am using a webpage that doesn't have validation for name field. If I give any special characters, the page just becomes unresponsive. Though the captcha times out after some time, the request still runs in the server.
Can we consider this as a target for potential DoS attack? If so, what are the steps I need to follow for creating PoC of DoS?

Answer (score 0):

simply a DoS attack means the attacker hits the target server with too many requests at the same time. as a result, the server will eventually fail to respond to all the requests. eventually, the server will crash or slowing down. in this case, if the request is not terminating, there is a potential vulnerability regarding DoS.

if you want to try out dos attacks simply you can use a tool like Low Orbit Ion Canon.

furthermore, if you didn't add any validations or if you are not sanitizing the text before saving to the database, there will be vulnerabilities exist for xss,sqli attacks.